# Steps to implement ANT through eclipse for creating Android Build

Tags: android, ant

I checked out many blogs for creating an ANT build script for an android project.
Many suggested creating it using the command line and quite few explained about creating it using eclipse, but the solutions don't work for me properly.

Can anyone please help me by specifying proper steps to implement ANT through eclipse for creating an Android Build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Eclipse way of doing this, you have to use `android update project`/`android create project`.
If you elaborate which parts of the command line process failed for you we could probably help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

I used this doc for doing just that. Always did it from command line. Specifically what you need is the "Update a Project" section in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Comment: I had gone through this document earlier also but it is through command line and what I want is through eclipse, Like the way we do in J2ME by right clicking on build.xml and it creates a jar file for deployment

Answer (score 0):

The link that @Eli Konki shared was very confusing to me. However I found this [article](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) that was pretty straight forward to follow. The only thing that didn't work for me was that I needed to add

```
<property file="build.properties" />
```

To my `build.xml` so that the properties I configured were acknowledged. Hopefully it will prove to be useful for you too.